# Math (geometry): Rectangle projection?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, geometry

In my app, the user can define three corners of a football field, using the iPhone's GPS, by walking over to the corners, one by one, and tapping a button. This works well, and I can draw the resulting rectangle on the screen similar to how it would appear in i.e. Google maps.

So I now have the map coordinates in latitude and longitude for three random corners of a football field.

There's no telling which corner the user starts at, nor if he/she enters the consecutive corners clockwise around the field or counter-clockwise.

What I then want, is for the full screen on the iPhone to represent the football field, so that the GPS position can be tracked on the screen.

So I need to compute the correct orientation to fit the field nicely on the screen, avoid inverting any of the axes, and rotate and scale the incoming GPS-coordinates to the screen's coordinate system.

How would you go about doing that? I don't need actual code, only what you would consider to be the simplest algoritm/strategy for achieving this.

I have already studied some articles on projection, rotation, etc., and I guess I could figure this out by lots of trial and error, but I would like to know the simplest way of doing this. Maybe iOS even has some functions for this that I am unaware of?

Comment: Are you still working on this? If so, are you dealing with football fields in just a small area (like just part of a state, for a high school team), or a large area (like the whole US, for a college or NFL team)?

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe problem shortly? First question what is input (I haven't caught).
Three dots and smth else? 4 numbers.

Why do you need if you can just get one coordinate and calculate then?

Comment: Input is two floating point values _GPSx_ and _GPSy_ (current GPS position).
Also available is floating point values c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y, c3x, c3y, representing the GPS position of the three recorded corners of the actual football field.

Comment: You can make 360 picture map from 36*n points then get the angle (Circle around of field, it's center is in center of field). For that you need. 1. Set 0 degrees point. 2. Calculate angle. 3. Choose pict according to this coordinate.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. I only need to show a mark on the screen that corresponds to where the user really is on the football field.

Comment: xOy and GPS point in it? What do you is is just [GPSx - Bottom] and [GPSy - Left] for example.

Comment: otherwise you need additional input.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the corners are visited in consecutive order (CW or CCW is irrelevant) you can compute the rectangle as follows:

if corners p, q, and r are visited in order, then corner s = p + r - q

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but since nothing has been accepted yet...

If the coords come as degree-minute-second, first you will have to convert to decimal degrees. Then pick one of the inputs.  Find the distance between that point and each of the other points (D=sqrt((lat1-lat2)^2 + (long1-long2)^2)).  Each distance will be one of three values - a width (along a goal line, for example - the shortest), a length (along a sideline), or a diagonal (one back corner of the end zone to the opposite back corner - the longest distance).  I don't know what these distances will be in decimal degrees - assuming you're dealing with a pretty small section of the earth, it will be constant tho, so the best bet is probably just go out to a local field and measure them yourself.  If you are dealing with a large part of the earth, then you need to convert from lat-long degrees to feet, which makes things extra ugly, but it can be done (if someone asks I'll add that part in an edit).  Once you know what corner you started with and what the other 2 corners you have are, you can figure out which distance you are missing and therefore what corner you are missing.  You can use the (lat1-lat2)/(long1-long2) ratio for one of the known distances above to figure out the orientation of the field.  Once you have that ratio and you know the distance you are missing, you have 2 equations and 2 unknowns - do a simultaneous solve and you have the coords of the 4th corner.

Add comments if you need more detailed steps & information.